# Function to check file in 2 file locations not working

Tags: function, powershell, file, automation, fileshare

I am trying to create a program that will copy files from our backup to archive directory using Powershell. I have two criteria in order for this program to run smoothly. One is that we have files from both current year and past years so only the files from this year must be copied over. Another is that we have to check to make sure that we are not copying over files of the same file name in case if the data in the file is accidentally modified.  Whenever I have this program not in a function, it works. But in a function, it gives me errors that it "cannot find the path" of the folder that I am copying from and the folder that I'm pasting the files to. I am going to use this for more than sixty locations, so it would be better that I don't have to rewrite the code in the function sixty times. I thought about using Robocopy, but I am still getting the same issues regardless with files not being copied over.

```
Function Copy-Data {

param (
    [system.object]$copyFolder,
    [system.object]$pasteFolder,
    [int]$currentYear,
    [int]$lastYear,
    [int]$nextYear)

    $copyItem = Get-ChildItem -Path $copyFolder
    $pasteItem = Get-ChildItem -Path $pasteFolder

    $copyCount = $copyItem.count

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $copyCount; $i++)
    {
        $copyName = $copyItem.Name
        $testPath = Test-Path "$pasteFolder$copyName"

        if ($copyItem[$i].LastWriteTime -gt $firstDate -and $copyItem[$i].LastWriteTime -lt $lastDate)
        {
            if ($testPath -eq $false)
            {
                Copy-Item -Path $copyFolder$copyName -Destination $pasteFolder
                #Robocopy "$copyFolder$copyItem[$i]" "$pasteFolder"
                Write-Host $pasteFolder$copyName
            }
        }
    }
}

$currentYear = Get-Date -Format "yyyy"
$lastYear = [int]$currentYear - 1
$nextYear = [int]$currentYear + 1
$firstDate = "12/31/$lastYear"
$lastDate = "01/01/$nextYear"

$copyFolder = "\\fileshare\test\copy\"
$pasteFolder = "\\fileshare\test\$currentYear\paste\"
Copy-Data ($copyFolder, $pasteFolder, $currentYear, $lastYear, $nextYear)
```

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that the function's verb is "check" but it's actually copying.

Comment: Also what are you actually trying to do?  Looks like you are only trying to copy files that don't already exist in the destination, but that overlooks files that might have the same name but are different.  If you're aiming for robocopy like functionality in an easier command you'll likely fall well short of it.  At any rate, if you can clarify it would help the discussion.

Comment: This is basic file mirroring. You have really over-complicated this. You could have just used the built-in robocopy.exe and use the mirror switch. The function is not properly named as per PowerShell guidelines. You are doing things that don't appear to be needed for your end goal.

Comment: To answer Abraham Zinala's question, I did not get an error in PowerShell. I am testing right now with 3 documents in one folder and 2 in another. If my program is right, the other folder should receive a third file. But nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Core code can be something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $copyFolder |
ForEach-Object{
    If( !(Test-Path $pasteFolder -Name $_.Name ) )
    {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $pasteFolder
    }
}
```

You can use just the destination path you don't have to give the full path of the destination file.

As a function it may look something like:

```
Function CopyFoldercontents
{
    Param(
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [String]$copyFolder,

        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [String]$pasteFolder
        ) # End Parameter Block.

    Get-ChildItem -Path $copyFolder |
    ForEach-Object{
        If( !(Test-Path $pasteFolder -Name $_.Name ) )
        {
            Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $pasteFolder
        }
    }
} # End Function CopyFolderContents
```

This could be more robust though, depends on what direction you want to take it.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.
You could just do this...
(validate what you are after on both sides, the construct the final function)

```
Function Start-FolderMirror
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias('mir')]
    Param
    (
        [string]$SourcePath      = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a source path'),
        [string]$DestinationPath = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a destination path')
    )

    $SourceFiles      = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File).FullName
    $DestinationFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationPath -File).FullName

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SourceFiles -DifferenceObject $DestinationFiles -IncludeEqual | 
    Select-Object -First 5
}

Start-FolderMirror -SourcePath 'd:\temp' -DestinationPath 'D:\temp\TestFiles'
# Results
<#
InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
D:\temp\TestFiles\abc - Copy - Copy.bat                     =>           
D:\temp\TestFiles\abc - Copy.bat                            =>           
D:\temp\TestFiles\abc.bat                                   =>           
D:\temp\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf           <=           
D:\temp\23694d1213305764-revision-number-in-excel-book1.xls <=  
#>

Function Start-FolderMirror
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('mir')]
    Param
    (
        [string]$SourcePath      = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a source path'),
        [string]$DestinationPath = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a destination path')
    )

    $SourceFiles      = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File).FullName
    $DestinationFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationPath -File).FullName

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SourceFiles -DifferenceObject $DestinationFiles -IncludeEqual | 
    Select-Object -First 5 | 
    Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -Match '<='
}

Start-FolderMirror -SourcePath 'd:\temp' -DestinationPath 'D:\temp\TestFiles' -WhatIf
# Results
<#
InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
D:\temp\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf           <=           
D:\temp\23694d1213305764-revision-number-in-excel-book1.xls <=  
#>


Function Start-FolderMirror
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('mir')]
    Param
    (
        [string]$SourcePath      = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a source path'),
        [string]$DestinationPath = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a destination path')
    )

    $SourceFiles      = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File).FullName
    $DestinationFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationPath -File).FullName

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SourceFiles -DifferenceObject $DestinationFiles -IncludeEqual | 
    Select-Object -First 5 | 
    Where-Object -Property SideIndicator -Match '<=' | 
    ForEach {Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.InputObject -Destination $DestinationPath}
}

Start-FolderMirror -SourcePath 'd:\temp' -DestinationPath 'D:\temp\TestFiles' -WhatIf
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\temp\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf Destination: D:\temp\TestFiles\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\temp\23694d1213305764-revision-number-in-excel-book1.xls Destination: D:\temp\TestFiles\23694d1213305764-revision-number-in-excel-book1.xls".
#>
```